# Save Google Search Console reports for offline reading/backup

Tags: google-search-console

Google's Search Console does provide useful information to a webmaster. One problem is that the data is only available for the last 3 months or so. Sometimes you'd like to get a larger scale overview of changes on a website.

How would you save Search Console reports (Crawl Stats / Indexed Pages / ...) for offline review later on?

One option is to save complete HTML pages and hope they load well on the browser but this doesn't seem like a clean solution as the associated JS doesn't always run well. Another option would be to print to PDF but that would not have the interactive graphs with their data.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Webmaster Tools is now called Search Console. There was no need to revert my changes.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. It's only changed like 9 months ago and the links still have the old name..

Answer (score 1):

i download WMT exports on following way:

- i manipulate the URL to WMT to adjust the datum (one day) and filter out some brand keywords (i don't want them in my reports)
- then i create manipulated URLs for each day of last 90 days, save them as list and
- run an iMacro to download all the data.

On this way i get 90.000 datapoints (1.000 á day).

To exclude more then one keyword from WMT the URL looks like

```
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics?hl=en&siteUrl=http://www.example.com/#state=
[null,[[null,"20160202","20160202"]],null,[[null,2,["keyword1"],2,1],[null,2,["keyword2"],2,1],[null,6,["WEB"]]],null,[1,2,3,4],1,0,null,[2]]
```

The part should be added for excluding, is `[null,2,["keyword1"],2,1]`, 
for including: `[null,2,["keyword"],2,0]`

Before pressing enter or running iMacros, URLs must be entity-encoded and look like

```
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics?hl=en&siteUrl=http://www.example.com/#state=%5Bnull%2C%5B%5Bnull%2C%2220160202%22%2C%2220160202%22%5D%5D%2Cnull%2C%5B%5Bnull%2C2%2C%5B%22keyword1%22%5D%2C2%2C1%5D%2C%5Bnull%2C2%2C%5B%22keyword2%22%5D%2C2%2C1%5D%2C%5Bnull%2C6%2C%5B%22WEB%22%5D%5D%5D%2Cnull%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C1%2C0%2Cnull%2C%5B2%5D%5D
```

Note, that Notepad++ if encode URLs, doesn't encodes comma - it should be encoded manually, with search and replace of `,` to `%2C`.

The iMacro code follows:

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE wmt-data.csv 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=6
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(11)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
```

Finally there are so many datapoints á day, like you wish - you can filter and export WMT data endless. All data are as CSV files: i build from them i.e. clients own CTR dashboards.

A really fine and useful thing would be, if somebody would write a VBA script, which would login into WMT, help on filtering exports, export data and import them into Excel.

Comment: Thank you for this details answer but many URLs on WMT don't seem to have a daily value to be extracted. Consider https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-errors?hl=en&siteUrl=http://example.com/ or https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-stats?hl=en&siteUrl=http://example.com/

Comment: Its free to you to add them into the URL. But if there are to few data in the search console to be shown for the given day, so you have to make the time interval experimentally a bit longer to get the data.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with what you're suggestion. Trying to suffix `#state=
[null,[[null,"20160202","20160202"]],null,[[null,2,["keyword1"],2,1],[null,2,["keyword2"],2,1],[null,6,["WEB"]]],null,[1,2,3,4],1,0,null,[2]]` to any of the URLs I've mention doesn't made any difference. Could you please include examples of info you've extracted this way?